# Is there any customized calendar that shows two weeks

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, calendar

I'm working on a customized calendar. I used `JTCalendar` but it didn't serve my purpose. In this `JTCalendar` there is week view which shows current week - if I swipe the calendar the next week will be loaded. But my purpose is to show two weeks per page. If I swipe the calendar the next two weeks should be shown.

Comment: @None: when editing, please note that inline code spans (`like this`) [shouldn't be used for highlighting](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254990), only for code in sentences. Also, please try and improve the post as much as possible when editing to save the reviewers time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Well If I were you, I'd use CollectionView to display the entries and put a swipe gesture on the collectionView, to load next two weeks. I am assuming you know how to extract date from iOS.